# Pin middle widget at the top while scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have Widget 1 positioned at the top (which is essentially a Column widget). Following that, there's Widget 2, and finally, a ListView. Initially, I want the entire page to be scrollable (whether I scroll over the ListView or outside of it). Subsequently, I want Widget 2 to remain fixed at the top while the ListView continues to scroll.

I've attempted various approaches to achieve this and stumbled upon implementations utilizing [SliverAppBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58096708/13014243). However, these implementations require a fixed height for Widget 1. The complication is that Widget 1 does not possess a predetermined height, and I want to avoid specifying any height at all.

Note that my Listview is actually a Future Builder

[image]

Comment: You can use `SliverAppBar(  pinned: true,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CustomScrollView` as follows,

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 100,
        child: Text('Widget 1'),
      ),
    ),
    const SliverAppBar(
      title: Text('Widget 2'),
      expandedHeight: 70.0,
      pinned: true,
    ),
    SliverList.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          color: index.isEven ? Colors.white : Colors.black12,
          height: 100.0,
        );
      },
      itemCount: 25,
    ),
  ],
)
```

If you need controll over group, try [SliverMainAxisGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverMainAxisGroup-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. SliverList.builder is not defined, might be depreciated. Instead, I used  SliverToBoxAdapter with the ListView in its child

Comment: try to use latest version of flutter sdk +project